# Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop - React with next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I've been told that this problem it's because i might be having this tag `<> </>` inside the map function, and that is the main reason for the error, but this is not the case and i'm still having this problem, let me show

[image]

Now, let me show some code

```
  <SearchResults>
              {results === "" ? (
                <NoSearch>No hay búsquedas recientes</NoSearch>
              ) : (
                <>
                  {filteredUsers.length > 0 ? (
                    <>
                      {filteredUsers.map(user => {
                        return (
                          <DisplayUsers
                            key={user.id}
                            whileHover={{
                              backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08)",
                              borderRadius: "1.2rem"
                            }}
                          >
                            <DisplayPhoto>
                              {user.perfil ? (
                                <img src={user.perfil} alt="" />
                              ) : (
                                <DefaultUser
                                  style={{
                                    width: "38px",
                                    height: "38px",
                                    borderRadius: "50%"
                                  }}
                                />
                              )}
                            </DisplayPhoto>
                            <DisplayName>
                              <h2>{user.name}</h2>
                              {/* <p>Amig@</p> */}
                            </DisplayName>
                          </DisplayUsers>
                        );
                      })}
                    </>
                  ) : (
                    <NoSearch>No hay resultados</NoSearch>
                  )}
                </>
              )}
            </SearchResults>
```

If i put the key in the main container, why am i still having this problem ?

If you can help me, you're the greatest, thanks !!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding unique keys for array children in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329382/understanding-unique-keys-for-array-children-in-react-js)

Comment: I think so... i tried to implement the solution, adding key to each child inside component ,but i still have the error

Comment: Ouu damn, the value of my id is undefined, i think that is the problem... But thank you for your answer, i couldn't even imagine how important keys are

Comment: I would suggest you to look for a package to handle that annoying aspect of React. There is a couple. Google that `react npm unique key`.